# Removing and adding Classes on Dropdown Menus on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a Navigation built that have drop down menus,

**HTML STRUCTURE LIKE SO**

```
<li class="c-header__subnav-item c-header__subnav-item-is-hidden c-header__subnav-item-is-visible-md">
    <a class="c-header__subnav-links u-caps js-c-header__subnav-trigger" href="#">
    Action Review Review
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-lg c-btn__icon-right-sm"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="c-header__subnav-dd">
        <li class="c-header__subnav-dd-item">
        <a class="c-header__subnav-links c-header__subnav-links--dd" href="#">
        Overview
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="c-header__subnav-dd-item">
        <a class="c-header__subnav-links c-header__subnav-links--dd" href="#">
        Review Form
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="c-header__subnav-dd-item">
        <a class="c-header__subnav-links c-header__subnav-links--dd" href="#">
        Performance Card
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="c-header__subnav-dd-item">
        <a class="c-header__subnav-links c-header__subnav-links--dd" href="#">
        Recent Recordings
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

When You Hover On the a.js-c-header__subnav-trigger
It addes a class to its self as well as its sibling ul ( the dropdown menu)

This is perfect but since the hover is triggered on the 'a' element If I toggle the class when and I go to hover on the drop down menu it gets removed before I can because of hovering off the 'a' element.

If I just add the classes and do not use toggle how would I remove both classes once I hover off the A element or Dropdown menu.

What needs to be achieved is

1.) If main nav link is hovered add an active class to itself and  drop down is triggered and can be seen. If you hover out WITHOUT engaging the dropdown both active and dropdown class are removed

2.) If main nav link is hovered add an active class to itself and if dropdown IS engaged by user keep both classes until dropdown is hovered out of or 'A' Element.

**CURRENT JQUERY CODE**

```
 ;(function($, window, document, undefined) {

 var $win = $(window);
 var $doc = $(document);
 var $classes = {

    SubNavTrigger           : 'js-c-header__subnav-trigger',
    SubNavItemActive        : 'c-header__subnav-item-is-active',
    SubNavDropDown          : 'c-header__subnav-dd',
    SubNavDropDownActive    : 'c-header__subnav-dd-is-active'

 };

var _isMobile = false;
_isMobile = ($win.width() <= 1024) ? true : false;


 // Check if  user is on touch on page load
 // if isMobile use click events
// if not mobile use hover events
if(_isMobile) {

$("." + $classes.SubNavTrigger).on('click', function(){

if ( $(this).hasClass( $classes.SubNavItemActive ) ){

  // If Item has active class removeClass

  $(this).removeClass( $classes.SubNavItemActive )

} else {

  // If Item does not have active class addClass
  $(this).addClass($classes.SubNavItemActive);

} //End if

// Add Active Class To Subnav.
$(this).siblings().toggleClass($classes.SubNavDropDownActive);

});


} else {


$("." + $classes.SubNavTrigger).on('hover', function(){

$(this).addClass($classes.SubNavItemActive);

// Add Active Class To Subnav.
// If set to toggle impossible to hover on this menu.

$(this).siblings().addClass($classes.SubNavDropDownActive);


 });
}

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Thanks In Advance for any help.

Live Site Link to see
http://100dc.vincebrown.me/integrity-pledge

Comment: Could you create a fiddle ?

Comment: about question #1: your dropdown is currently triggered on CLICK, is your purpose to modify the trigger to fire your dropdown on HOVER?

Comment: here is a jsfiddle, I commented out the `_isMobile`: http://jsfiddle.net/jwzr9L3s/

Comment: about #2: what do you mean with "if dropdown IS engaged by user"?

Comment: @depperm you forgot the link..

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio By engaged by User I mean that they go to hover on the dropdown 
example

1.) User hovers on nav link dropdown appears and they dont see what they want so never enter the drop down.

2.) User hovers sees what they want and goes into dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would make a few changes, I would move the `s-c-header__subnav-trigger`class to the parent `li`. I would then change the jquery to use the [hover(in,out)](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). The in function would look something like

```
function () {
  $(this).addClass($classes.SubNavItemActive);

  // Add Active Class To Subnav.
  $(this).children().addClass($classes.SubNavDropDownActive);
}
```

and the out

```
function () {
  $(this).removeClass($classes.SubNavItemActive);

  // Add Active Class To Subnav.
  $(this).children().removeClass($classes.SubNavDropDownActive);
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6joc1ydx/1/)

Comment: THANKKKK YOU !
Working like a charm